# Download Object from S3 compatible storage using AWSSDK

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I was trying to download an Object using a third party service url (without region) rather than amazon. It allows to manipulate bucket ( put / delete / copy ) but can not download.

```
AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();
config.ServiceURL = "http://s3.de.test.test.com";

AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
                accessKey,
                secretKey,
                config
                );

ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest();
request.BucketName = "mybucket";
ListObjectsResponse res = s3Client.ListObjects(request);

GetObjectRequest req = new GetObjectRequest();
req.BucketName = "mybucket";
req.Key = res.S3Objects[3].Key;
GetObjectResponse response = s3Client.GetObject(req);
```

after calling the GetObject it returns error

> 'The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'DE''

are there any possible ways to download the object without region from AWS SDK or any other possible SDKs for C# without using HttpClient or WebClient

Thanks